# Querying Project Gutenberg catalog.rdf via SPARQL

Tags: rdf, sparql

I'm having difficulty structuring a SPARQL query for the Project Gutenberg catalog (available at [Gutenberg Feeds](http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Gutenberg:Feeds) toward the bottom of the page).  I know it is a fundamental lack of understanding on my part of how SparQL/RDF/etc. actually work, conflating it with SQL, etc.  But I've tried several tutorials, and I just can't quite get my mind around piecing the WHERE clause together with what seems to be the multidimensional dataset.

I have imported catalog.rdf into a TDB database (from the Jena project), and am using the tdbquery tool to set up my query initially, before I wrap it into a command-line tool that allows searching by author or title.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$ cat gutenquery.tq
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX dcmitype: <http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/>
PREFIX cc: <http://web.resource.org/cc/>
PREFIX pgterms: <http://www.gutenberg.org/rdfterms/>
PREFIX dcmitype: <http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/>

SELECT ?title ?author
WHERE {
    ?book dc:title ?title  ;
          dc:creator ?author
}
LIMIT 10

$ ./tdbquery --loc=/var/db/gutenberg/ --file=gutenquery.tq
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| title                                                                                               | author                                                       |
======================================================================================================================================================================
| "The Belgian Curtain\nEurope after Communism"^^rdf:XMLLiteral                                       | "Vaknin, Samuel, 1961-"^^rdf:XMLLiteral                      |
| "Fairy Tales; Their Origin and Meaning\nWith Some Account of Dwellers in Fairyland"^^rdf:XMLLiteral | "Bunce, John Thackray, 1828-1899"^^rdf:XMLLiteral            |
| "The World English Bible (WEB): Zephaniah"^^rdf:XMLLiteral                                          | "Anonymous"^^rdf:XMLLiteral                                  |
| "Lectures of Col. R. G. Ingersoll - Latest"^^rdf:XMLLiteral                                         | "Ingersoll, Robert Green, 1833-1899"^^rdf:XMLLiteral         |
| "Selections from Erasmus\nPrincipally from his Epistles"^^rdf:XMLLiteral                            | "Erasmus, Desiderius, 1469-1536"^^rdf:XMLLiteral             |
| "East and West\nPoems"^^rdf:XMLLiteral                                                              | "Harte, Bret, 1836-1902"^^rdf:XMLLiteral                     |
| "The Enormous Room"^^rdf:XMLLiteral                                                                 | "Cummings, E. E. (Edward Estlin), 1894-1962"^^rdf:XMLLiteral |
| "The Enormous Room"^^rdf:XMLLiteral                                                                 | _:b0                                                         |
| "Actes et Paroles, Volume 4\nDepuis l'Exil 1876-1885"^^rdf:XMLLiteral                               | "Hugo, Victor, 1802-1885"^^rdf:XMLLiteral                    |
| "L'ÃŽle Des Pingouins"^^rdf:XMLLiteral                                                               | "France, Anatole, 1844-1924"^^rdf:XMLLiteral                 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

A typical entry from PG looks like this, although not all fields are present in all records:

```
<pgterms:etext rdf:ID="etext7250">
  <dc:publisher>&pg;</dc:publisher>
  <dc:title rdf:parseType="Literal">A Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur's Court, Part 9.</dc:title>
  <dc:creator rdf:parseType="Literal">Twain, Mark, 1835-1910</dc:creator>
  <pgterms:friendlytitle rdf:parseType="Literal">A Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur's Court, Part </pgterms:friendlytitle>
  <dc:language><dcterms:ISO639-2><rdf:value>en</rdf:value></dcterms:ISO639-2></dc:language>
  <dc:subject>
    <rdf:Bag>
      <rdf:li><dcterms:LCSH><rdf:value>Americans -- Great Britain -- Fiction</rdf:value></dcterms:LCSH></rdf:li>
      <rdf:li><dcterms:LCSH><rdf:value>Arthurian romances -- Adaptations</rdf:value></dcterms:LCSH></rdf:li>
      <rdf:li><dcterms:LCSH><rdf:value>Britons -- Fiction</rdf:value></dcterms:LCSH></rdf:li>
      <rdf:li><dcterms:LCSH><rdf:value>Fantasy fiction</rdf:value></dcterms:LCSH></rdf:li>
      <rdf:li><dcterms:LCSH><rdf:value>Kings and rulers -- Fiction</rdf:value></dcterms:LCSH></rdf:li>
      <rdf:li><dcterms:LCSH><rdf:value>Knights and knighthood -- Fiction</rdf:value></dcterms:LCSH></rdf:li>
      <rdf:li><dcterms:LCSH><rdf:value>Satire</rdf:value></dcterms:LCSH></rdf:li>
      <rdf:li><dcterms:LCSH><rdf:value>Time travel -- Fiction</rdf:value></dcterms:LCSH></rdf:li>
    </rdf:Bag>
  </dc:subject>
  <dc:subject><dcterms:LCC><rdf:value>PS</rdf:value></dcterms:LCC></dc:subject>
  <dc:created><dcterms:W3CDTF><rdf:value>2004-07-07</rdf:value></dcterms:W3CDTF></dc:created>
  <dc:rights rdf:resource="&lic;" />
```

In addition to, e.g. dc:author and dc:title, I'd like to get the value from the attribute of pgterms:etext rdf:ID="STUFF IN HERE":

```
<pgterms:etext rdf:ID="etext7250">
```

As well as combining the entries in the list under dc:subject, etc.  Basically, provide all the info on this book as a single coherent entry via the command-line query.

So, my questions:

1. How can I combine the attribute value from pg:eterms rdf:ID with the rest of the query?
2. How can I combine the entries under dc:subject's list into one string?
3. Since not all fields show up for every record, should I use the OPTIONAL() clause to surround fields that don't always appear?
4. How can I limit my query based on a user-specified string?  Am I supposed to use FILTER() for that?

Thank you so much.  I have been able to construct queries to get single-layer information, but anything beyond that, attributes etc.  are nigh inscrutable to me.  This is much different to standard SQL, and a much more involved project than I thought at first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How can I combine the attribute value from pg:eterms rdf:ID with the
>   rest of the query?

The RDF id, will be the URI of the book in your kb. In your case putting ?book into your select clause will bring it back.

> How can I combine the entries under dc:subject's list into one string?

I am not sure about this. You can put dc:subject into your query and then itterate with your client.

> Since not all fields show up for every record, should I use the OPTIONAL() clause to surround fields that don't always appear?

Yes

> How can I limit my query based on a user-specified string? Am I supposed to use FILTER() for that?

Yes, specifically `FILTER regex()`

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful and straightforward.  I have it sorted now.  I don't have enough points to upvote you yet, but that answered my questions.